# I can't see Malware code whine I use any editor

Tags: security, malware

I have Malware code (java), I can see the code using (view source), I can't see bad code when I use any editor to delete the code, My domain is pointed to CloudFlare. What do I need to do to see the code and delete?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable line wrapping in editor. It is possible lines with bad code begin with many spaces and code shifted from begin of line to place where it need to scroll to right.

Comment: What you mean by that? Your question ask about code that is invisible in text editor. I explain answer exactrly to question how it is tipically may be done. Your question is about java code but this comment show javascript code. If you have some more question try to create more questions.

Comment: If you meant that some javascript code fetch bad code from url and execute that. Therefore code which dowload bad code itself bad code too. So remove bad code that download some other bad code.

Comment: Hi oklas,
this code or java code I can see it when I use ((view-source:http://www.eg-malls.com/index.html)) I need to remove it, I can't see or edit by any other html editing, what I can dooooo??

Comment: So you meant that that code is not exists in files on your server but appear when you download page via url in browser. Here on stackoverflow you may get help only if your problem is fully described. Yes malware worked silently. And it is not possible to solve task without fully described environment or without access to it. Do not post access to it here but only description. You need to examine your server environment. Try to ask on freelancers boards.